# NoClassDefFound trying to use java class and docx4j from grails controller

Tags: java, grails, groovy, noclassdeffounderror

I have a groovy file that is trying to call some methods from a Java class that I have set up using docx4j to parse .docx files

When I set up a pure java test program in eclipse, I am able to do this fine. However, when I have my .groovy file set up, I get no compilation errors, but at runtime I get this stack trace:

```
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/docx4j/wml/RPr

at org.jsecurity.web.servlet.JSecurityFilter.doFilterInternal(JSecurityFilter.java:382)

at org.jsecurity.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:180)

 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/docx4j/wml/RPr

at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)

at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2395)

at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1763)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:33)

at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:20)

at ResumeController$_closure8.doCall(ResumeController.groovy:119)

at ResumeController$_closure8.doCall(ResumeController.groovy)
```

I can't quite figure out what the problem is - here is the relevant portion of thre groovy file:

```
 import mypackage.DocxHelpers.DocxParser;
 import org.docx4j.*;
 class ResumeController{
 def save = {

    File f=new File('c:/dev/temp/test.docx');
    uploadedFile.transferTo(f);

    DocxParser doc=new DocxParser(); //line 119
    def resume=doc.openDocx4j(f);
    f.delete();
    resumeInstance.entireResume=resume;
    flash.message="Resume parsed";
    render(view:'create',model:[resumeInstance:resumeInstance]);

 }
 }
```

My java stuff related to DocxParser is in the src folder under my project folder, and the docx4j jar is in the lib folder.

Do I simply have my imports defined incorrectly, or are the files in the wrong place?

Comment: your java code is on the src/java directory... and the package information and imports have been verified in those files?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have the `docx4j` JARs on your runtime classpath. The code above seems to belong to a Grails controller. Have you checked that the class referred to by the `NoClassDefFoundError` is present within the `docx4j` JAR(s) in the Grails `/lib` directory?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that class that isn't found is in the org.docx4j.wml package, but the import statement refers to org.docx4j package.  Try changing the import to `import org.docx4j.wml.*;`.